How to save data entered in a custom modal using Filament?
I am working on a Laravel project using Filament, and I want to create a custom modal to gather input from the user and save that data. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly handle and save the form data inside this custom modal.
For instance, I have created a Filament Action and used a custom modal to take some inputs:
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('relation_order_id')
    ->label('Related Record No')
    ->sortable()
    ->searchable()
    ->action(
        Action::make('customModal')
            ->label('Custom Modal')
            ->modalHeading('Custom Modal Heading')
            ->modalContent(function ($record) {

                // Here I'm returning a Blade view where I want to gather information from the user
                return view('filament.modals.custom_modal', ['record' => $record]);

            })
            ->modalWidth('lg')
    )
    ->color('primary')
    ->toggleable();

Inside this modal, I want to create a form and need to be able to save the data entered by the user. Here's what I have in the Blade file:
resources/views/filament/modals/custom_modal.blade.php


<div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="custom_field">Custom Field</label>
            <input type="text" id="custom_field" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <!-- Save Button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>

However, I'm not sure how to handle and save the custom_field data entered by the user with Filament.
My Questions:
How can I capture the data entered by the user in this custom modal?
How can I save the form data using action() or any other suitable method?
Is it possible to use a Livewire component within Filament’s custom modal to handle this, or is there another recommended way for handling such form submissions?
Any examples or guides would be greatly appreciated!

Related to the documentation, what says:
The data from the form is available in the $data array of the action() closure:

You should have an action closure, and there will you get your data
Action::make('customModal')
    ->label('Custom Modal')
    ->modalHeading('Custom Modal Heading')
    ->modalContent(function ($record) {
        // Custom view
    })
    ->action(fn($data, $record) => dd($data)); // Action to handle form data from modal

I recommend taking a look at the documentation for more information.

I tried this way but my array returns empty.
